# Convert Expression<Func<DTOUser, bool>> predicate to Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate

Tags: c#, expression, predicate

I have a problem in Expression

I have an Entity

```
public class User{ 
public string Username{get;set;}
  public int PhoneNumber{get;set;}
  public string FIrstName{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

and I have a DTO

```
public class DTOUser{
  public string Username{get;set;}
  public int PhoneNumber{get;set;}
  public string FIrstName{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
  }
```

Then I have a snippet code generic

```
 public IList<DTOUser> SelectAll(Expression<Func<DTOUser, bool>> predicate)
    {
           using (var adc = _conn.GetContext())
        {   
       // what should I do ?? so i can convert Predciate to get all values from Users (Entity)   
//it generates an error because predicate can't be cast into Entity User                    
 //   var users = adc.Users.All(predicate);
       }          
    }
```

I wanted to get a list of DTOUser by Passing LAMBDA Expression

```
accountrepo.SelectAll( user => user.firstname.equals ("sample"));
```

I have researched this issue and come to the conclusion that because DTOUser and User are of different type, it's difficult to cast the Expression from one type to another.

One solution has been suggested by Jon Skeet:

[How to cast Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> to Expression<Func<T, object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729295/how-to-cast-expressionfunct-datetime-to-expressionfunct-object)

but as this solution seems that I have to map each value from DTOUser to User doesn't this make it more complex as my DTOUser contains more than 15 properties.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: @user751959 As I understand your problem, you want to apply expression expecting type DTOUser on object of type User. Could you edit the question, so that it is more clear?

Comment: Don't know how to delete my duplicate flag, I just read too fast. My apologies.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš what i want is to convert Expression<func<DTOUsers,bool>> to Expression<func<Users,bool>> so that the predicate can be accepted by 
adc.Users.All(predicate);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast directly from one type to another, you can do:

1. a manual mapping
2. map automatically using reflection (as propery names are the same)
3. Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

For mapping using reflection, you can use the following generic code :

```
public static T1 CopyProperties<T1, T2>(T2 model)
    where T1 : new()
    where T2 : new()
{
    // Get all the properties in the model
    var type = model.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    var result = new T1();
    var resultType = result.GetType();
    var resultProperties = resultType.GetProperties();

    // Loop through each property
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var resultProperty = resultProperties.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == property.Name && n.PropertyType == property.PropertyType);
        if (resultProperty != null)
        {
            resultProperty.SetValue(result, property.GetValue(model, null), null);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It will copy properties with the same types and names

Comment: There are 24 tables in the old solution. If i start writing manual mapping it would take a lot of time and cost in code maintenance. Please if you can elaborate the second approach with a small code example i.e., the automatically using reflection.

Comment: AutoMapper should be a great solution as the classes have the same property names

Comment: Thanku for helping me out really thanks i prefer using Automapper .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Jon Skeet's answer from your link, and define an explicit cast from DTOUser to User in your User (partial) class:

```
public static explicit operator User(DTOUser dto)
{
    return new User
    {
        Prop1 = dto.Prop1,
        Prop2 = dto.Prop2,
        ...
    }
}
```