# How to cast expression in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having expression

```
Expression<Func<TSource, string>>
```

I am cast it to  `Expression<Func<TSource, object>>`

using as

```
As Expression<Func<TSource, object>>
```

But gives me null every time .

as string is reference type so it should not do so.

even `Expression<Func<TSource, MyClass>>` this expression also gives null on conversion.

Comment: You can't cast expressions directly like that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729295/how-to-cast-expressionfunct-datetime-to-expressionfunct-object

Comment: @Sean Not exactly the same thing, `DateTime` is a value type, so `Func<DateTime>` cannot be treated as `Func<object>` directly. `Func<string>` *can* be treated as `Func<object>` directly, and making it work for `Expression<Func<string>>` and `Expression<Func<object>>` is easier than making it work for `Expression<Func<DateTime>>` and `Expression<Func<object>>`.

Comment: @hvd Fair enough, thanks for the explanation =]

Comment: thanks guys. My function can take any argument that is Expression<Func<Tsource,int>>  i want to return some expression which has to support any type i.e value as well as reference type. So what should be my return type expression. As Expression<Func<TSource,object>> will support for only reference type. I think it not possible to support value and reference type at same type. As all the value types are in struc will it help for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func<TSource, string>` and `Func<TSource, object>` are different types, therefore `Expression<Func<TSource, string>>` and `Expression<Func<TSource, object>>` are also different types.

There is an implicit conversion from `Func<TSource, string>` to `Func<TSource, object>`, but this exception has not been extended to `Expression<T>`, and in general, such exception extensions would *not* be safe, even if it might be safe here.

You can, however, create a new expression, and copy the body of your older expression.

```
Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => "Hello";
Expression<Func<object>> expr2 =
  Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(expr.Body, expr.Parameters);
```

Comment: I do think you mean `Expression.Lambda<TSource, object>(Expression.TypeAs(expr.Body, typeof(object)), expr.Parameters)`

Comment: @Aron No, I don't. You might need to encode some sort of cast if you're dealing with a value type, but a reference type doesn't need that when you're implicitly converting to one of its base classes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you cannot cast from `Expression<Func<TSource, string>>` to `Expression<Func<TSource, object>>` with a simple using.

As @hvd said, you need to create a new expression and copy the older expression.  However, since that example does not show the same signature as the question, here is what it looks like with the TSource input parameter.

```
var newFunc = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(oldFunc.Body, oldFunc.Parameters);
```

and, as @aron showed, the following is correct if the return type of the expression does not implicitly convert to object.

```
var newFunc = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(
        Expression.TypeAs(oldFunc.Body, typeof(object)), oldFunc.Parameters);
```