# convert Expression<Func<t, bool>> into Expression<Func<x, bool>>

Tags: c#, expression

Is it possible to convert or cast on expression of type y to an expression of type x?

class y

```
public class y
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

class x

```
public class x
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

expression

```
Expression<Func<y, bool>>
```

How can I cast/convert it to

```
var t = (Expression<Func<x, bool>>)Expression<Func<y, bool>>
```

?

Thanks 
Rui

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/q/729295/1870760

Comment: @GillBates Don't think so, `object` is the global base class, while `x` and `y` in this question have no relationship.

Comment: @Kroltan: even without a predefined relationship, the basic idea is still the same. The expression object will have to be recreated, with suitable conversion to map the one parameter type to the other. The marked duplicate has plenty of information describing that basic approach. If the OP needs help beyond that, they need to post a new question which includes a good [mcve] showing what they've already tried, based on the information available, and explaining what _specifically_ they are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relationship between `x` and `y`, you can't, at least not as a cast.

What you can do is provide a conversion from `x` to `y`. Generically, something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TB, TReturn>> ConvertExpression<TA, TB, TReturn>(
    Expression<Func<TA, TReturn>> expr,
    Func<TB, TA> converter
) {
    return (TB input) => expr.Compile()(converter(input));
}
```

Then, to actually convert the expression, you'll need to provide a conversion from `y` to `x`:

```
ConvertExpression(yourExpressionX, yVal => new x {ID = yVal.ID});
```

Comment: Whilst the code seems exactly what I was after, a converter, I get 
System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
When doing the Where with EF.

Comment: @Rui Hmm. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with LINQ to Entities. It seems to work quite okay without it, so I suspect it is a limitation on that library. You might want to find an alternative solution, then. Perhaps ask a more specific question including the details of where you're using it, with a [mcve] using L2E so people with knowledge in that can help you.