# Unable to cast object of type 'LogicalBinaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[T,System.Boolean]]'.'

Tags: c#, database, linq

`TestData` is `System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression`

I have convert to `Expression<Func<Experience, bool>>` this format its occur error

```
Expression<Func<Experience, bool>> C1 = (Expression<Func<Experience, bool>>)TestData;
```

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException
> HResult=0x80004002
> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[CCIP.Shared.ModelsCCIP.Experience,System.Boolean]]'.
> Source=CCIP.Data
> StackTrace:

Comment: How did you get `TestData`? Please add code for building it.

Comment: Instead of casting, see if `Expression.Lambda(TestData)` works. I doubt you can cast an expression to lambad expressions just like that.

Comment: A `LogicalBinaryExpression` is not a `Func<,>`. If you have `Func<int,bool> f = true && true;` what would you expect? If you want a lambda, you must create one with `Expression.Lambda()`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729295/how-to-cast-expressionfunct-datetime-to-expressionfunct-object) can help?