# How do interfaces work inside generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a method like the following:

```
public IQueryResult<TEntity2> SwapQueryEntity<TEntity2>(Expression<Func<TEntity, List<TEntity2>>> entitySwapMap)
{
       return new QueryResult<TEntity2>(_query.SelectMany<TEntity, TEntity2>(entitySwapMap));
}
```

Where `_query` is of type `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

However I am getting the following error on the parameter to the `SelectMany` method:

```
Cannot convert from System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, System.Collections.Generic.List<TEntity2>>> to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity2>>>
```

So the issue seems to be that it wont recognise the result type of the expression of `List<TEntity2>` to be assignable to `IEnumerable<TEntity2>` despite the fact that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

I am not seeking an answer as to how to make my code "work". I could simply change the method signature to use `IEnumerable` instead of `List` and my problem goes away.

What I would like to gain is a deeper understanding of why this issue is occuring and why the compiler won't recognise a `List` as an `IEnumerable` in this case?

Comment: It’s a bit hard to say from this one, but I assume it’s because you’re not trying to put a `List` into something that takes `IEnumerable`. You’re trying to put something that has a `List` inside it to something else. Just like you can’t directly assign a `List<string>` to `List<object>` even though `string` can be used as an `object` by itself (covariance/contravariance might be the words here if I remember correctly)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do two layers deep in generic parameters. I will investigate covariance/contravariance to see if it can help me.

Comment: It's not about `List` and `IEnumerable`. It's about the *expression* types. Since Expression is a class it's not co/contravariant.

Comment: @GertArnold Is there any reason why Expression class is not variant when the Func class is?

Comment: AFAIK Func is a delegate type, not a class

Comment: I believe `Expression<Func<TEntity, List<TEntity2>>> entitySwapMap` should be `Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TEntity2>>> entitySwapMap`.

Comment: My question isn't about how to "fix" the code to make it work, so I will put my solution to this problem as a comment in case anyone finds it useful. In the end I simply found this following method to cast my expression to the required type:

`var body = entitySwapMap.Body;`

`var param = entitySwapMap.Parameters.Single();`

`var newEntitySwapMap =  Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TEntity2>>>(body, param);`

I must give credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27463773/18365832) for helping me get to this solution